# Ошибка при введении пароля через subprocess

Tags: python, linux, cron, subprocess

Есть скрипт в cron, при его выполнении возникает следующая ошибка:

```
2021-12-27 09:10:08,688 - ERROR - modules.bl_parser.check_dns 
- b'[sudo] \xd0\xbf\xd0\xb0\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8c \xd0\xb4\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8f bg: '
```

Вот кусок кода, который отвечает за эту ошибку:

```
try:
    password = self.password+'\n'
    password = password.encode()
    stdout, stderr= subprocess.Popen(['sudo', '-S', 'cp',\
                                      '/home/bg/new_parser_bg/zones.bl', '/etc/bind/zones/'],\
                                      stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,\
                                      stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate(input=bytes(password))
    if stderr:
        log.error(stderr)
        sys.exit(1)
```

Такая ошибка возникает обычно при выполнении через крон, в чем причина?

Comment: Это точно весь текст ошибки? Там нет собственно содержания - что за ошибка то.

Comment: @CrazyElf 2021-12-27 09:10:08,688 - ERROR - modules.bl_parser.check_dns - b'[sudo] \xd0\xbf\xd0\xb0\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8c \xd0\xb4\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8f bg: ' Это всё, что записало в log.

Comment: @CrazyElf Как я понимаю, это не ошибка в Python, это ошибка из stderr.

Comment: За идею гонять в кроне sudo с паролем надо бить грязными тряпками. Ошибка явно на русском языке, что-то про bg

Comment: От чьего имени запускается крон?

Comment: @AlexeyTen От имени пользователя bg.

Comment: Текст данной "ошибки" - `[sudo] пароль для bg: `. Может скрипт просто пароль спрашивает, но печатает запрос в stderr, а вы интерпретируете это как ошибку?

Comment: @GrAnd зачем оно печатает запрос в stderr, это же поток для ошибок.

Comment: Да кто ж его знает. Никто же не запрещает. Может чтобы текст не кешировался (stderr по умолчанию не кешируется).

Answer (score 0):

В общем, я добавил:

```
time.sleep(1)
```

```
password = self.password+'\n'
password = password.encode()
time.sleep(1)
stdout, stderr= subprocess.Popen(['sudo', '-S', 'cp',\
                                  '/home/bg/new_parser_bg/zones.bl', '/etc/bind/zones/'],\
                                  stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,\
                                  stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate(input=bytes(password))
```

Как я понял, скрипт выполнял следующую строку не дожидаясь password.encode()

Comment: Скорее уж `communicate` нужно делать отдельной строкой после паузы.

Comment: Кстати, после `encode` у вас уже `bytes` в `password`, ещё раз в `bytes` явным образом их не нужно переводить.

Comment: @CrazyElf точно.

Comment: @CrazyElf как только я убрал bytes, опять появляется та же ошибка.

Comment: Очень странно. А не пробовали всё-таки `communicate` отдельной строкой делать и паузу перед ним поставить?

Comment: @CrazyElf ещё нет, попробую.

Comment: @CrazyElf сделал, всё так-же пишет ошибку когда убираю bytes().